# Xuggler could not open output url error

Tags: java, stream, media, xuggler, xuggle

I've been following the simple video tutorial on youtube [Xuggler](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdW6tUql154). I've made sure that an existing file path is in the argument. However I still get the following error:

15:15:44.339 [main] DEBUG com.xuggle.xuggler - Could not open output url: *thefilepath (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/Container.cpp:436)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not open
    at myproject1.MediaPlayer.main(MediaPlayer.java:23)
Java Result: 1

---

My code is below:

public class MediaPlayer {

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    if(args.length != 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no file");
    IContainer container = IContainer.make();
    System.out.println("args: " + args[0]);

    if(container.open(args[0], IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not open");
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause Could be un-availability of dependency jars or version conflicts.

Adding the following jars in the classpath worked fine for me:

xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
logback-core-1.0.0.jar
logback-classic-1.0.0.jar

Comment: Yeah I didn't realise I had to include the latest version dependencies. Thanks

Comment: @AVA I have added these jars but still getting same error

Comment: Can you please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490599/could-not-open-output-container-for-live-stream-using-xuggler-youtube-broadcas